# Transcendence degree of product of intermediate fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $E_1,E_2$ are intermediate fields, then

(i) tr.d.$E_1E_2/K \ge$ tr.d.$E_i/K$ for $i= 1,2$;

(ii) tr.d.$E_1E_2/K \le$ (tr.d.$E_1/ K$) + (tr.d.$E_2/ K$).

tr.d. denotes the transcendence degree.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I don't know how to prove either of these.  I know that tr.d.$E_1/K=$tr.d$E_1/E_2 +$ tr.d.$E_2/K$. So (tr.d.$E_1/K$) + (tr.d.$E_2/K$) = tr.d.$E_1/E_2 + 2$tr.d.$E_2/K$. But that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: But tr.d.$E_1/E_2$ is not defined unless $E_1\supset E_2$. Beyond all this, it’s generally considered best to tell the audience how much you already know, and what you’ve tried. Have you drawn a picture of the inclusions among the various fields?